# Webcam Optimization Program w/ OBS -- White Balance, Auto Exposure, Etc.

Tags: webcam, streaming

I broadcast live feeds daily and unfortunately have to use Windows 10 with XSplit Broadcaster because this enables me to tweak settings such as auto exposure (biggie here), white balance, and so on.

On Ubuntu, I have OBS - OBS doesn't pull up webcam options that allow you to make changes to your auto exposure when running Ubuntu (I am on 17.04, about to upgrade).

I have used GTK UVC which is a wonderful program except that I'm unfortunately not understanding their auto exposure settings very much. On Windows, for instance, I use -4 or -5 exposure, but on GTK UVC it seems exposure is measured in the +1000s. This one option alone makes my feed look 'washed out' no matter what number I seem to move the slider to.

Here is my question: Does anyone know of a program that works on Ubuntu that mirrors Windows' webcam customization options?

Incase it matters, I am using the Logitech Brio. Thank you so much for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out so I wanted to post an update here incase anyone else should run into a similar problem. Hopefully this works for you!

I was not able to find any program that works in a similar way to Windows' webcam customization options - namely,exposure settings. On Windows you simply turn off auto exposure and then move the slider to -4, -5, -6, etc. and tweak it to meet the requirements of your camera/lighting/scene.

The problem arises when using GTK UVC. GTK UVC has all of the same options that you'd find in Windows + more. However, the auto exposure settings are completely different. After what seemed like hours of playing with settings I finally got it. Here is the secret formula (lol):

Set exposure to manual. If you used -4 in Windows, move the slider to 400. If you used -5 in Windows, move the slider to 500. If you used -6 in Windows, move the slider to 600. Essentially, whatever the number was in Windows, add two zeros and make it a positive. Done!